# Renault Fluence voltage source under dashboard

Tags: power, renault

I want to connect an electrical device that runs on 12V or less voltage.

Where can I connect it from **below the dashboard** (the lighter doesn't count, unless it has an under the hood part).

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information to answer it well. Does the device need exactly 12V, "automobile 12V", approximately 12V, or some specific voltage less than 12V? Do you want it always-on, or switched by the ignition? Permanently connected or just temporary? While the vehicle is moving? Does it have its own fuse?

Comment: Thank you for the response! It is an arduino device. It could run from anywhere between 5V to 16V on extremes, and it doesn't really matter if it runs on ignition or all the time. The preference is to use it while the car is on, to save energy. And permanently connected, but preferably without soldering.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have spade fuses, you can use one of these [spade fuse taps](fuse spade tap) to get your power:

[image]

It fits over the blade on the fuse, then you push the fuse down into its normal position in the fuse panel. You can connect the other end to a grounding point. To find one look for a metal nut or a bolt in the vicinity of your fuse panel.

When you do connect it, ensure you do two things. First, make sure you are pulling power from before the fuse and not *through* the fuse you are using. This will ensure you are not drawing more power than the fuse can handle. Second, use an inline fuse to support your equipment. This will protect the car and the equipment should there be a shorting issue going on.